# Check for Turtles behind current turtle

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am aware of the turtle commands to check for turtles **ahead** of the current turtle.

```
if not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1


if( any? other turtles in-cone 10 1)
```

But how would you check for turtles behind a turtle?

Comment: `patch-ahead -1` is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [patch-ahead help](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/patch-ahead.html) from the official documentation.

Based on the documentation provided there, syntax is like this `patch-ahead distance` so if you want to look back you should use:

```
patch-ahead -1
```

However, using this you will look on patch back in the current direction of the turtle. If the direction of the turtle changes you should consider storing the direction in the previous time step and use something like this (pseudo-code):

```
set t_dir heading
tick
patch-at-heading-and-distance t_dir -1
```

---

Or just store the patch that turtle of interest is on in the previous time-step and check if another turtle is on that patch in the current time-step.